# How to use feh to open web image with self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, feh

I'd like to use `feh` to open an image located on a server using a self-signed certificate. Is there any way to achieve this? I checked the man page in hope of finding something similar to `curl`'s `-k`, but no such luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `curl`'s `-k` is convenient for you, you might just want to use it, actually:

```
curl -sk https://domain.tld/path/to/image.png | feh -
```

The dash here will have `feh` read the image data from the standard input. With this trick, you can let the "downloading" part to `curl` (which is what `feh` uses internally anyway) and pipe everything to `feh` for display. You're basically splitting what `feh` combines back into two parts, in order to enjoy the full set of options and features of each component.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! You'd think the idea of piping the data from a program that does what you want would be a natural first go-to for a linux user...not feeling too skillful atm.

Comment: Perhaps you also have the answer to my follow-up question (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231817/pipe-multiple-file-from-curl-to-other-program)? :P